# How to join two streams in kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to join two streams in Kafka like following code.

```
@Bean
public KTable<String, String> stream(StreamsBuilder builder) {
            KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier store =
            Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("words");
    JsonSerde<String> wordSerde = new JsonSerde<>(String.class);
    KStream<String, String> stream = builder
            .stream("topic-a", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), wordSerde));

    return stream.join(
                    builder.stream("topic-b"),
                    (w1, w2) -> w1+w2,
                    JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(10)),
                    StreamJoined.with(Serdes.String(), wordSerde, wordSerde))
            .toTable(Materialized.<String, String>as(store)
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(wordSerde));

}
```

but when I'm trying to read from `KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier` it is just only reading from `topic-a`.

updated:
I published some messages to both topics.
for example in `topic-a` I sent *Hi* message and same message in `topic-b` what thing that I expect is merging two words together. *HiHi*

```
@PostMapping("publish/{word}")
fun publishEvent2(@PathVariable(value = "word") event: String){
   kafkaTemplate2.send("topic-a", event,event)
}
```

Did I miss somethings?

Comment: Can you add to the question some example records you are sending to both topics?

Comment: @PawełSzymczyk I did, does make sense? let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please specify messages in format: key: xyz, value: qwe. Join is made by messages key, so if you not specify the same key, join will not be executed.

Comment: @PawełSzymczyk I'm using spring boot. so for sending message I use kafkaTemplate. see updated. same for topic-b as well.

Comment: unrelated: your data is just a string, not JSON, so you should use Serdes.String rather than wordSerde

Comment: Are you sending the data within the same 10 seconds? If not, make your window larger. If you dont want a time window, then make topic-a into a KTable, then join topic-b against that...

Comment: I've just copied the code and everything works as expected. I've changed two things: window time to ten minutes, and value serde to Serdes.String()

Comment: @PawełSzymczyk Yes, last night tried again and it was ok. :( I'm sorry for silly question.